# UITableView dynamic size

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

In my main view I have a header (label) and footer (button). In the middle there is a table. Table takes data from MutableArray so number of table items is different each time.

Before and behind a table I have some vertical spaces (set by constraints) because I want to have some space between header/footer and table. So now a table is spread over whole "middle" part. This is OK.

What I want achieve to is that I don´t want to spread it over whole middle part. I want table to resize according to its content. If a table has only one row, I want to show one row and none of empty rows. I tried this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {    

     int count = accController.connectedAccessories.count;

     [tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.contentSize.width, tableView.rowHeight * count)];
     return count;
}
```

But this doesn't work. If I add this line after `setContentSize`:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
```

This works but If I have many of items, constraints are broken and table is over a footer. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks

EDIT: This header and footer aren´t part of the table. I just put label (I call it header) and button (footer) into main view. And between them I put a table. It looks better for my purpose. I call it header and footer but they are header/footer of the main view, not a table...

Answer (score 1):

pass a blank view as viewForFooterInSection may help you.

Try this---

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this code which solves your question

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If you want to add backgroung image to the cells use this code

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
```

Answer (score 1):

please do as per following in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *tempDataArray;
    UITableView *tblVIew;
}

@end
```

in .m file

```
#define cellHeight 30
#define headerHeight 50
#define footerHeight 50


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //[myMapView addAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)];
    myScroll.hidden=YES;

    tempDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item1", nil];
    [self generateTableView];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tempDataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
    cell.textLabel.text=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return cellHeight;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return headerHeight;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return footerHeight;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *lblHeader=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 200, 30)];
    [lblHeader setText:@"Header"];
    [lblHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblHeader setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    [lblHeader setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [lblHeader setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    return lblHeader;
}
// custom view for header. will be adjusted to default or specified header height
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 220, 40);
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = frame;
            [button setTitle:(NSString *)@"Footer" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"temp1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [myScroll addSubview:button];
    return button;
}
// custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default or specified footer height

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // code for redirecting to another view
   // use button tag property for identifying perticular record
    [self generateTableView];
}

-(void)generateTableView
{
    tblVIew=nil;
    [tblVIew removeFromSuperview];

    [tempDataArray addObject:@" new item"];
    tblVIew=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 50, 220,(cellHeight *[tempDataArray count])+headerHeight+footerHeight)];
    tblVIew.delegate=self;
    tblVIew.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:tblVIew];
    [tblVIew reloadData];
}
```

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try belowing code. I hope it may help you

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
   tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
   [tableView reloadData];
   tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, [self tableViewHeight] );

}
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight
{
    [_tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    return [_tableView contentSize].height;
}
```